# Why there is no migrations detected but I just created new migrations?

Tags: django, data-migration

This is my workflow, everything seems nice and tidy with **makemigrations** and **migrate**. However, I want to start over with my models, so I:

1. rm -rf all the migrations file in the django app directory;
2. drop all the related tables in the database;
3. makemigrations results in new migration files;

But when I want to migrate it into database, it is said **No migrations to apply**. I think the mechanism behind migrations is that models -> migrations -> database changes, if I drop the latter two it should go over again. Unfortunately it is not.

Django == 1.8.2

**CLOSED** There is a table called *django-migrations* tracking all the changes and delete related records and then I could make migrations. Thx to those who helped!

Comment: What version of django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another table that keeps track of which migrations have been ran for each app, django_migrations. You'll have to reset that in order for django to know you have started over.

if you changed the database already then try running

`python manage.py migrate <app> --fake zero`

Comment: what does that mean by 'fake'?

Comment: well because you said you already dropped the tables you wouldn't be able to run migrations backwards to the zero state (pre-initial state). It would fail trying to alter tables that don't exist anymore. "fake" essentially tells django to run the migration file without making any changes to the actual database.  

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake