# No model tables are created for a Django migration

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

I have searched other articles (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802911/why-there-is-no-migrations-detected-but-i-just-created-new-migrations)) for a solution, but nothing has helped so far...

I realized while working on my project that I needed to alter the model, changing a primary key to an AutoField rather than use a custom field. I knew this would cause a lot of issues since I have quite a few ForeignKey fields, so I wanted to drop all of my tables, clear out the migrations, and just let the migrations re-generate all of the the tables. The problem is that even though I dropped all of the tables (and eventually the whole database, due to the django_migrations table and any other latent data), cleared out all of the project/app/migrations directories, when I run manage.py makemigrations/manage.py migrate, it only creates the built-in tables (the auth_* and django_* tables) and none of my model tables get recreated.

Where else do I need to clean up in order to be able to start over with a fresh database model? I thought that clearing out the migrations directories would be sufficient, but there's something else I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: but you haven't cleaned the migrations table, right? I think you need to do `./manage.py migrate your_app zero --fake`, then you can do the usual makemigrations + migrate

Comment: Did you leave an `__init__.py` file in the migrations folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have deleted the migrations folder for an app, you have to specify the app name to create the initial migrations:

```
./manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was missing.